# Is it possible to somehow change the value of a derived store directly?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently working with SvelteKit.

I have a `derived` store, which is necessary because it depends on another store. Now I need to change some values in the `derived` store directly. The problem is that `derived` stores are not modifyable as far as my understanding goes.

Is there any way to change the value of a `derived` store directly?

For example if I'd have a `derived` store called `tiles` which is an array of objects and I would like to change the property of one of its objects (`$tiles[n].x = 'something new'`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a derived store writable by simply adding a `set` function.

You will need either access to the source object from which the value is derived or you need to merge the new value in a way that preserves the relevant object references. (Though in the latter case you may still need to do a dummy reassignment on the parent store, to trigger an update.)

E.g.

```js
const parent = writable({ items: [{ name: 'pochi' }, { name: 'maru' }]});
const items = derived(parent, value => value.items);
items.set = newItems => $parent.items = newItems;
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b3db1726c02e494986ac266f09b35240?version=3.49.0)

Comment: Thanks for the reponse.
Could you take a look at this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ff50d687e82f446c92b8b9a51915487c?version=3.49.0) example and tell me how I would go about including it there?

It's still quite confusing for me.

Comment: @h-thilo: You can't, because all the data the store returns is fully generated. If you want things to be mutable, you have to pull them out of the function that generates the store.

Comment: @h-thilo: This would be the simples approach: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d865c8d9bb6e499bae285d903a6851bc?version=3.49.0) - Note that this will not be able to handle replacements, it just mutates the existing items and triggers an update.

Comment: @h-thilo Here would be a more complex example that allows replacement of the whole tile set, depending on the current setting: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cf14da6b88f74a7c97371e4a843ef3da?version=3.49.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your effort! Interesting examples!
However, I managed to find a relatively simple way to do what I wanted to do. I simply pass the other `writable` store as function paramter to the other `writable` store. This way I don't have to rely on derived stores. 

Here the example: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7cc032c2c9384422980916bdfb1d925d?version=3.49.0)

Comment: That is just a function, at least in that example there is no need for the store at all ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/61e47b6c81244000b18d25441189d5b8?version=3.49.0)).

Comment: Yeah in my current code I think it does make sense. I need to share those values over multiple components and my code is much longer. 

Can't really put that all into the REPL though.