# How to correctly pass properties of a nested Svelte Store to child components

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, store, svelte-store

i have a Svelte Store with a nested object inside.
(I don't want to flatten the store, since in my real use-case the order of the elements (arrays appear too) is very important.)

```js
export const rootStore = writable({
    test : {
        a : 0
    }
})
```

Now i want to pass the `test` property of this store to a child component, and I am questioning myself, what would be the best way to do this.

I did it like that:
Parent.svelte

```js
<script>
    import Child from "./Child.svelte"
    import {rootStore} from "./store.js";
    
    rootStore.subscribe((value) => console.log(value))
</script>

<Child attributes={$rootStore.test}/>


<p>
    Value of test.a is {$rootStore.test.a}
</p>
```

Child.svelte

```js
<script>
import {rootStore} from "./store.js";
export let attributes;
    
    const triggerUpdate = () => {
         $rootStore = $rootStore;
    }
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={attributes.a}/>

<button on:click={triggerUpdate}>
    Explicitly trigger update
</button>
```

But this doesn't seem a good idea, since now i am working on a reference of `item` in my child component, that does not trigger other subscribers when I edit `a`.
The edit will only become visible when I explicitly update the `rootStore` object as done in `triggerUpdate()`.

Here is the full REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/57bce526799843b19838913cd598f201?version=3.50.1

Is it necessary to always work on the `$rootStore` in the child components?
Should I only pass some IDs as properties to the child component, that will not be changed anytime?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to `bind` the property to make it hook into updates:

```html
<Child bind:attributes={$rootStore.test}/>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8324c76ae2254069972ead0a5d702072?version=3.50.1)

Comment: Hey thank you, this was an easy fix, but for some reason I didn't come to this myself...

Comment: May I ask another question?
I realized that my original question was covering only one case, where i want to pass the reference down to other components.
But sometimes I just need a deeply nested value from the store and want to use some kind of reference to it instead of always writing the full path (especially when array come into place).
I had two ideas about how to do this, but none of this worked when updating the value.
https://svelte.dev/repl/7bd43f9ca4bb44559a603bfbdf2b3e37?version=3.50.1

If you can have a look this would be really nice, otherwise I post this as another question

Comment: Sorry wrong link the first time. Now it's correct

Comment: You can work with derived stores to split off values, regular variables will not work. Example [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/73354ace6455484b90c52d7384cd6ade?version=3.50.1); this extends the derived store with a `set` that causes the original store to trigger its subscribers. ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73427634/is-it-possible-to-somehow-change-the-value-of-a-derived-store-directly/73427791))

Comment: Thank you very much ! You saved my day.
I always skipped the derived stores chapter, because i couldn't think of a use case for me, but now I know one (of many) :)

Comment: You are welcome. (Note that this example does not handle full value replacements, e.g. something like `$soos1 = { b: 42 }`, for that you need to add some additional logic besides/instead of the dummy update.)

Comment: ([E.g.](https://svelte.dev/repl/15ea8339e65940b1b273b52bc90d790c?version=3.50.1) `soos.set = value => rootStore.update(x => { x.soos = value; return x });`)

Comment: Good point, thanks for the hint.